# How can I find the factorial of each value inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, math

Say the user input a word which has repeated letters inside it. Every repeated letter will get stored with the factorial of its count. e.g. assuming the user input is *talahasee*, it has 3 *a* and 2 *e* which will be 6 and 2 if we take their factorials. The rest of the letters will be 1 since they occur once.

How can I find the factorial of each value inside a dictionary?

My current code looks like this.

```
def pwr():
    word = input("Word: ")
    n = len(word)
    fn = math.factorial(n)
    x = Counter(word)
    for i in x:
        no = math.factorial(i.values())
        print(no)
```

If you are wondering, I am making a program that follows the permutation with a repetition formula.

Comment: Try `for n in x.values(): no = math.factorial(n)`

Answer (score 0):

As I got your question, you mean finding the factorial of each element in a python dictionary. Factorize is not the same as the factorial that you used in your sample code. Factorize means finding the prime divisors of a number.

Anyway, I believe the following code will do what you need:

```
from collections import Counter
from math import factorial

def dict_factorial(input_string):
    fd = {}
    d = dict(Counter(input_string))
    for k in d:
        fd[k] = factorial(d[k])
    return fd
print(dict_factorial("Tallahassee"))
```

output: {'t': 1, 'a': 6, 'l': 2, 'h': 1, 's': 2, 'e': 2}

Besides, the correct spelling of the word is "Tallahassee" in Florida :-)